# How to reduce button's size along when its text size is reduced too?, in html and css

Tags: html, css

Here's the code
I'm a beginner so if there's any mistake that I should also improve on, please correct me.

```css
button {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: roboto, Arial;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(59, 102, 241);
  border-radius: 100px;
  border-width: 0px;
  width: 190px;
  height: 25px;
  caret-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(87, 125, 250);
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
Please put HTML here!
```

I want the button to 'shrink' when clicking, I tried reducing width and height but it shrinks to a certain corner instead of middle.

Comment: Perhaps you can add the HTML to the snippet I started for you that reproduces this right here in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your Button CSS you are setting the width and height with no padding. But in your active state you aren't changing the width and height but slightly changing the padding.

You have a few ways to accomplish what you are looking for.

You can either ignore the width and height and use padding, or in your active state change the width and height.

I have two different buttons showing how you use either method of changing the width/height vs padding.

```css
button {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: roboto, Arial;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(59, 102, 241);
  border-radius: 100px;
  border-width: 0px;
  caret-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(87, 125, 250);
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 5px 40px;
}

.padded{
  padding: 10px 80px;
}

.padded:active {
  font-size: 9px;
  padding: 5px 40px;
}

.dimensions{
    width: 190px;
    height: 35px;
}

.dimensions:active{
    width: 130px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<button class="padded">Pad Change</button>
<button class="dimensions">Width/Height Change</button>
```

Comment: *i tried reducing width aand height but it shrinks to a certain corner instead of middle.*. I think your button is also shrinking like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to center you button horizontally and vertically. Then the desired effect will happen.

I quickly done this with on old trick to center elements. Probably flex is the best options to center things horizontally and vertically

```css
button {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: roboto, Arial;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(59, 102, 241);
  border-radius: 100px;
  border-width: 0px;
  caret-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.container {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}

.container button {
  margin: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(87, 125, 250);
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
  font-size: 8px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

.dimensions{
    width: 190px;
    height: 35px;
}

.dimensions:active{
    width: 130px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<button class="dimensions">Change button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "super center" the button by using `display:grid;` and then `place-items:center;` on a wrapper element.  Experiment with this by simply changing the font size in the wrapper container - since I used EM for the measure you can change everything in one place size-wise.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.button-container {
  /* uncomment this to see your original size smaller button */
  /* font-size: 0.625em; */
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: solid #00FF00 1px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.my-button {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #3b66f1;
  border-radius: 6.25em;
  border-width: 0px;
  width: 12em;
  height: 1.5em;
  caret-color: transparent;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.my-button:hover {
  background-color: #577dfa;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.my-button:active {
  font-size: 0.75em;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background-color: #577dfa44;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="my-button-test">Click me then click TAB to focus:My Button and it spacebar to make it "active"</button>
<div class="button-container">
  <button type="button" class="my-button">My Button</button>
</div>
```